# C++ Count type of characters (uppercase, lowercase, digits, special) WITHOUT if-else, ternary, or switch case. Any IDEA?

Tags: c++, count

C++ : How do I Count no. of characters for each type of characters (uppercase, lowercase, digits, special) WITHOUT if-else, ternary, or switch case. Any IDEA?

Comment: *Any IDEA?* I'm sorry I'm not very IntelliJ.

Comment: You could build an array that has an entry for each character and maps it to a particular character-type value.  Then you're really just doing pointer math to determine what kind of character you're looking at.  There are lots of other possibilities too.  Is there any particular motivation for this question?

Comment: @Borgleader I'm sorry this comment hasn't received the recognition it deserves.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) with the corresponding binary functors.

Answer (score 2):

With a `std::map` (you may use `char[256]` instead):

```
std::map<char, std::function<void()>> m = {
    {'a', [&]() {++lowercase;} },
    // ..
    {'z', [&]() {++lowercase;} },
    {'A', [&]() {++uppercase;} },
    // ..
    {'Z', [&]() {++uppercase;} },
    {'0', [&]() {++digit;} },
    // ..
    {'9', [&]() {++digit;} },
};
```

and then

```
for (char c : characters) {
    m.at(c)();
}
```

Comment: And then have fun with UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

For example the following way

```
size_t count = 0;

count += std::isdigit( c ) != 0;
```

If to use the range based for statement you can write

```
std::string s( /*Some string */ );

enum { UPPERCASE, LOWERCASE, DIGIT, PUNCTUATION, SIZE = 4 };
size_t count[SIZE} = {};

for ( unsigned char c : s )
{
    count[UPPERCAsE]   += std::isupper( c ) != 0;
    count[LOWERCASE]   += std::islower( c ) != 0;
    count[DIGIT]       += std::isdigit( c ) != 0;
    count[PUNCTUATION] += std::ispunct( c ) != 0;
}
```

Also you can define an array of these functions. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string s( "There is text, 12345,.?!" );
    int (*check[] )( int ) = 
    { 
        std::isupper, std::islower, std::isdigit, std::ispunct 
    };

    const size_t N = sizeof( check ) / sizeof( *check );
    size_t count[N] = {};

    for ( unsigned char c : s )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) count[i] += check[i]( c ) != 0;
    }

    for ( size_t n : count ) std::cout << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1
10
5
5
```